# UIPopoverController showing empty frame

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

So I am trying to display a `UITableView` inside a `UIPopoverController` using the piece of code shown below

```
vc = [[ActionsViewController alloc] init];
initWithContentViewController:vc];
actionsController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
actionsController.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"Try to sho it ");
[actionsController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

And this is ActionsViewController.m which is a subclass of `UITableViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray* list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    self.actionList = list;
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 400.0);
    [self.actionList addObject:@"Print as book"];
    [self.actionList addObject:@"Print page"];
    [self.actionList addObject:@"Save Page"];
    [self.actionList addObject:@"Share"];
}
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"in number of section");
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString* lab = [self.actionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"here in there");
    cell.textLabel.text = lab;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.actionList count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.delegate != nil) {
        [self.delegate actionSelected:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

The corresponding .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol KLActionsViewControllerDelegate
- (void)actionSelected:(NSInteger)index;
@end

@interface KLActionsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* actionList;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<KLActionsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

Also, I don't think the functions `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` are getting called because I don't see any console output.

EDIT: This is what I see in the popover

:[image]

Comment: When you say `actionsController.delegate = self` who is self? I'm assuming your not in ActionsViewController.m. From what I can tell, you just need to move that line into your 'viewDidLoad' to assign ActionsViewController to be the delegate of the tableView. And don't forget your dataSource. See [Creating a UITableView Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356695/creating-a-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically)

Comment: In 'viewDidLoad' I added 'self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init]' after which it shows the empty table.
To add the datasource I added self.tableView.dataSource = self but it still doesn't load up the data. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @vishalv2050 did you ever figure this out? I am currently having a problem with this too. I'm assuming you also followed Apple's ToolbarSearch example from their website?

Comment: @Chris Not really, got frustrated after spending hours on it. Picked up a working sample from some location and then made changes to it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the problem would be in that line:

```
vc = [[ActionsViewController alloc] init];
```

if you have a NIB file, you should load the `UIViewController` with using it.

```
vc = [[ActionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActionViewController" bundle:nil];
// the NibName must be the exact name of XIB file without extension.
```

---

**OR/AND**

you should set the `popoverContentSize`:

```
[actionController setPopoverContentSize:vc.view.frame.size];
```

I hope it helps a bit for you.

---

**UPDATE:**

it seems it is not an `UIPopoverController` problem, just a simple `UITableViewController` delegate issue.

in that line:

```
actionsController.delegate = self;
```

you should set that class as delegate which implements the `UITableViewDelegate`. basically it is the `UITableViewController` itself like

```
actionsController.delegate = actionController;
```

therefore you should **not** replace this in that case if you haven't implemented the delegate callback methods in the `self` which the new delegate class is. you simple steal the chance from the class which was really delegated to answer the callbacks, and in you new delegate class you don't answer the callbacks.

this would be the reason why you are seeing the empty table, without the datas.

Comment: I don't have a nib file. Setting the popoverContentSize did't help either. I can see the blank UItableView .

Comment: I don't see in your code fragment where you set the `popoverContentSize`, please, make a screenshot what you see then when the popover would show.

Comment: @vishalv2050, just because that line `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 400.0);` in an another `UIViewController` class won't set the size of _your_ `actionsController`. it will set the content size for a totally different popover.

Comment: I have added a screenshot now

Comment: okay, it seems it is definitely not a `UIPopoverController` problem. have you logged the content of `list` in your `-viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: Yes, I have. It contains the objects entries as it is supposed to.

Comment: is your ActionsViewController a delegate of the `UITableViewController` class? have you implemented the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in your class? have you set the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties?

Comment: because for me, it seems your `UITableViewController`'s delegate property points to another class which is not a real delegated class of it, you set the incorrect delegation in this line: `actionsController.delegate = self;` and the current class does not answer to the callback methods.

Comment: `actionsController` is of type `UIPopoverController'.
And I have set the datasource and the delegate in my class. You can see it in the .m file

Comment: this is the point I can't see in that code fragment how you set the delegates... could you publish the whole `.m` and `.h` files? I think there is a little mess in your code what it does not show from the current fragments.

Comment: I have added the .h file too now.

Comment: @vishalv2050, the `UITableViewController` has a `delegate` property already, this is the definition of it: `@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate`. you simply override this property in this line: `@property (nonatomic, assign) id<KLActionsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;` with a totally different protocol. why? you must rename you own `delegate` property for the `KLActionsViewControllerDelegate` protocol and do not override the original `delegate` property one with something else.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` I added `self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init]`

Comment: This line will override the tableview defined in the NIB and create a new one, whatever connections were defined in the NIB, datasource, delegate etc. will need to be recoded again. If you are using UITableviewÇontroller as the parent class - take out this line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the table view via (last line of viewdidload :

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

- that will trigger the table view methods to action. Put a breakpoint in the various tableview methods particularly in -
  (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
     {
     return [self.actionList count];
      } 
  If this does not get called your tableview is not loaded.

Comment: One other things that you need to ensure - In the XIB file, make sure the  delegate, datasource, and view are linked to File owner (ActionViewController).  You will know if this is the problem by setting up breakpoints in the tableview delegate methods, if it runs and there is data but no display - this is the problem.  You can start debugging from there.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController is implicit  set datasource and delegate, there is no need to set explicitly datasource and delegate.

Remove UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate from .h file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol KLActionsViewControllerDelegate
 - (void)actionSelected:(NSInteger)index;
@end

  @interface KLActionsViewController : UITableViewController 
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* actionList;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) id<KLActionsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


 @end
```

and also remove this line ****actionsController.delegate = self;**

```
  vc = [[ActionsViewController alloc] init];
 actionsController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
  [actionsController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```