# Tableview doesn't fire cellForRowtIndexPath method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

**My situation:**

- I've got `datasource` and `delegate` connect in the storyboard
- I've got for my `UITableViewCell` and identifier and also in code defined, etc.
- I've got the `array` with data for my `UITableView`, in debug my data `array` is filled in `viewDidload` method

So everything seems right till I arrive to `cellForRowIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection`. It doesn't go into the methods. When I
 run further, debug is complete, don't get any faults, only a black
 `UITableView` i get with nothing in. Really strange cus my array is
 filled with data and everything is connected as it should be.

Some help is needed, i'm searching for days now!

If code is needed to help, ask me.

**My code:**

***m.file:***

```
#import "DagprogrammaDetailViewController.h"

@interface DagprogrammaDetailViewController ()
@end

@implementation DagprogrammaDetailViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *DagprogrammaDetail;
}

@synthesize menuNaam;
@synthesize tableDagprogrammaDetail;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = menuNaam;

    NSArray *dagarray = [menuNaam componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *plaatsString = [dagarray objectAtIndex:1];
    plaatsString = [plaatsString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    //object ophalen
    NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://zesdaagse.mobi-app.be/WCFUrl/MobileService.svc/GetDagprogramma"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *id = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSDictionary *item in json)
    {
        [id addObject:[item objectForKey:@"id"]];
    }

    int plaats = [plaatsString intValue];
    plaats -= 1;
    //id van de dag ophalen
    NSString *idDagprogramma = [id objectAtIndex:plaats];

    urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://zesdaagse.mobi-app.be/WCFUrl/MobileService.svc/GetDagprogrammaWedstrijden?id="];
    [urlString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",idDagprogramma]];

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *idWedstrijdDagprogramma = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *naam = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *uur = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSDictionary *item in json)
    {
        [idWedstrijdDagprogramma addObject:[item objectForKey:@"id"]];

        [naam addObject:[item objectForKey:@"naam"]];
        [uur addObject:[item objectForKey:@"uur"]];
    }

    DagprogrammaDetail = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

    for(int i = 0; i < json.count; i ++)
    {
        NSMutableString *lijn =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [naam objectAtIndex:i]];
        [lijn appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%s", "\t \t"]];
        [lijn appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [uur objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [DagprogrammaDetail addObject:lijn];
    }
}

//methode om aantal items te weten van de array
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [DagprogrammaDetail count];
}
//methode om een item aan een index te koppelen en zichtbaar te maken
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuDetailCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableDagprogrammaDetail dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    cell.textLabel.text = [DagprogrammaDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Check that the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is returning 0 ?

Comment: one reason could be if you implement numberOfSection method and it returns 0.

Comment: type [tblview reloadData]; and print array count in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Is tableview IBOUTLET connected?

Comment: @BuntyMadan It's automatically returning 0 because it's not firing up that method. That's my problem, when i debug it doens't go into those 2 methods. so yes it's 0.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout,it's the expected behaviour. If you dont have any section, how did you expect to create row in a section that doesn't exist

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout No .. its actually `IBOutlet`. Wasn't really concentrating on syntax.

Comment: Have you tried ? : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16172169/1603072

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout What's about `YourClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` ?

Comment: Just check by calling [yourtableview reloadData]; on viewDidLoad method.

Comment: If it's black, it isn't added to the stack/window

Comment: @mstfbsnli I'm very confused right know, so you know how to fix it? Cus in other view controllers it works fine and it's same code and methods. What should i do?

Comment: @Simon It's only the table view and it's in de stack or what do you mean? You mean if it's in the GUI?

Comment: Try to `NSLog` your `[array count]`, if its `Zero` you may look at your `array` if its `alloc` or not

Comment: @Mutawe my array with data counts 13..

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout, that's right. is it added to the UIWindow or corresponder viewcontroller? If it's completely black, it isn't added. UIWindow shows a black color as it's background, and if you didn't add any viewcontrollers, the look of your app will be completely black.

Comment: @Simon So i've got a table view dragged from the list on the right corner into the view controller and I don't know really what you mean with UIWindow. Indeed it's my table view that's black completely. My navigation bar is like it should be and works like it should be. So what do I have to do exactly cus I think you have the answer for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm very confused right know, so you know how to fix it? Cus in other
>   view controllers it works fine and it's same code and methods. What
>   should i do?

- Calm Down and Recheck your Code again. I guaranteed that it'll be some silly mistake. It may happens to anyone when you are frustrated.

**Things you can do :**

**1)** `NSLog` your `numberOfRowsInSection`. Note that , If it's **"0"** then your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never going to be called.

**2)** If you are using your `UITableView` inside some `UIView` then you should add :

```
[self.view addSubview:table];
```

**3)** Don't Forget to include :

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: 1) it's 0
2) doesn't work directly, where do you place it?
3) included.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : That's the Problem. Your `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning `NULL`. You have no values in your Datasource.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : You have to add some Data in your Array. Your Array (from which you are trying to populate your Table) is Empty.

Comment: There are 13 items in my array, how do you explain that?

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : If it's the case then Why your `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning `NULL` ?

Comment: these all possibilities already discussed in comments issue is something else please show your code or recreate your project and follow all the step.

Comment: @BuntyMadan : Check OP's 1st comment !!! Issue is that His Array is being Empty for some reason.

Comment: @Vin We are not magician so without code any developer can't do anything as i already told

Comment: @BuntyMadan : Agreed. But I think He got where he has Problem. Now he should have that Basic Knowledge to solve the Error. We are not here for Spoon Feeding.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : `NSLog` `DagprogrammaDetail` as Last Line in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Cannot use NSLog, got error DagprogrammaDetail needs to be convert into String or something

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : Have you write it like this : `NSLog(@"yourArray :: %@",DagprogrammaDetail);`

Comment: This is the print: 2013-05-21 14:24:51.252 ZesdaagseGent[2951:11303] myarray :: (
    "Voorstelling\t \t20:00",
    "Ploegafvalling\t \t20:20",
    "Puntenrit\t \t20:40",
    "Tijdrit\t \t21:00",
    "Ploegkoers\t \t21:20",
    "Derny\t \t22:30",
    "Afvalling\t \t22:45",
    "Derny\t \t23:00",
    "Tijdrit 500m\t \t23:15",
    "Derny\t \t23:40",
    "Scratch\t \t00:00",
    "Supersprint\t \t00:15",
    "Ploegkoers\t \t00:30"
)
So like I said my array is filled..

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : write the same line in `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"myarray :: %@",DagprogrammaDetail);
    return 1;
}
Here I don't get anything in log. Like I said, the methods of my tableview doesn't fire up.

Comment: Do onething , instead of calling your API in `ViewDidLoad` , call that in `ViewDidAppear` And then Reload the table view. ex: **[yourTable Reloaddata]** Also add Break point in all Delegate/ datasource method of tableview

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota Did that and i've set a break point in all delegate datasource methods of the tableview, they dont' go in those methods..

Comment: Check my answer its working fine , I just used your code only. The problem with your code was you didn't allocated the array Properly.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : Simply Remove this Line : `DagprogrammaDetail = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];` and add this Line : `DagprogrammaDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in your Project.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : Oh.. I can only say that : Calm Down and Recheck your Code again. I guaranteed that it'll be some silly mistake. It may happens to anyone when you are frustrated. (First Line of My Answer)

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : Try to write `[yourTableName reloadData];` as last line of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You must understand, i don't know nothing about objective c and iOS. Suddenly you are dropped by your boss to do project without any education in that language thats why i'm getting frustrated, sorry lost all my reputation points cus of my fustrations :(

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout : If you find "My Effort" worthy then atleast Accept the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I Just Changed Little-bit in ViedDidLoad and its working fine

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = menuNaam;

    NSArray *dagarray = [menuNaam componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSString *plaatsString = [dagarray objectAtIndex:1];
    plaatsString = [plaatsString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    //object ophalen
    NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://zesdaagse.mobi-app.be/WCFUrl/MobileService.svc/GetDagprogramma"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *idss = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];;

    NSLog(@"Json Data =%@",json);
    for(NSDictionary *item in json)
    {
        [idss addObject:[item objectForKey:@"id"]];
    }

    int plaats = [plaatsString intValue];
    plaats -= 1;
    //id van de dag ophalen
    NSString *idDagprogramma = [idss objectAtIndex:0];

    urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://zesdaagse.mobi-app.be/WCFUrl/MobileService.svc/GetDagprogrammaWedstrijden?id="];
    [urlString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",idDagprogramma]];

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *idWedstrijdDagprogramma = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *naam = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *uur = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSDictionary *item in json)
    {
        [idWedstrijdDagprogramma addObject:[item objectForKey:@"id"]];

        [naam addObject:[item objectForKey:@"naam"]];
        [uur addObject:[item objectForKey:@"uur"]];
    }

    DagprogrammaDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i = 0; i < json.count; i ++)
    {
        NSMutableString *lijn =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [naam objectAtIndex:i]];
        [lijn appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%s", "\t \t"]];
        [lijn appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [uur objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [DagprogrammaDetail addObject:lijn];
    }
}
```

Download my project [Here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/FI1HJV1c/DagprogrammaDetail.html)
Link: http://www.4shared.com/zip/FI1HJV1c/DagprogrammaDetail.html

Comment: I placed this code into my project but it runs and i get black table view with you're code. Because my delegate and datasource methods don't fire up for some reason, if I find that reason it should work i guess..

Comment: download the project : http://www.4shared.com/zip/FI1HJV1c/DagprogrammaDetail.html

Comment: Okay, i've got it but in my project we don't use .xib files and also..you work with 1 screen. In my project you click on an item in an other table view and then you go to DagprogrammaDetail. And it's that page that doesn't react on the delegate or datasource methods..you don't use storyboard.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota I really appreciate your effort, but I guess this is a waste of time :(

Comment: @MarcMosby Thanks for your appreciation , i just wanted to help.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout if you are not using Xib file , then why you are Using IBOutlet ?

insted of **IBOutlet UITableView *tableDagprogrammaDetail** , use **UITableView *tableDagprogrammaDetail**  and in `ViewDidload` write the Code to create Tableview Programatically.

Comment: Check this answer on How to create tableview programatically : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356695/creating-a-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota I'm working with storyboard then you don't have to programmatically create controls. You drag and drop from list of controls. Removing IBOutlet doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for us knowing what is going on if you won't post your full code. Obviously you missed something. Follow this step by step [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) against your code to find where your problem hides.

Comment: It's nothing with the code, cus i've got my data. ;) And I used this tutorial already.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. There is method called  :
`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`

You don't have to implement this method, because by default it returns 0. So if you implement this method and this method returns 0, you got problem. As you don't have any section, your datasource methods to create a row never gets called because you don't have any section in your tableview.

To make it work, either you don't implement

`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`

method at all, or it has to return at least 1.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout, could you provide code block where you create your table view, so i can help you more

Comment: But I don't create one, drag and drop from the list.

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout How is it possible, you need to implement required datasource methods, how did you implement datasource methods ,just provide them

Comment: @SigfridMaenhout,add [self.tableview reloadData] once you finished fetching data in your viewDidLoad()